# How can I implement Random in java

Tags: java

Well, I need to implement two classes `Student` and `School`. Each student has an `Id` number consisting of `number of arrival` and the `dormitory number`, the second one should be random number from an array of elements.

Then I need to register these students to appropriate schools, there  are four of them. This registration have to be random also. so I have Student and Schools classes here,

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private int id, size;
private int dorm;

/**
 * Constructor of a class Student
 *
 * @param n sets the name of the student
 */
public Student(String n) {
    name = n;
    int d[] = {11, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 38, 39};
    Random r = new Random();
    dorm = d[r.nextInt(d.length)];
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


/**
 * @return the dorm
 */
public int getDorm() {
    return dorm;
}
/**
 * the id to set
 */
public void setId() {
    id = size;
    id = id*100 + dorm;
}


/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}


@Override
public String toString() {

    String result = "The student " + name + " has an id " + id + ". Located in the dormitory #" + dorm + ".";
    return result;

}
```

And School class here,

```
import adt.Queue;

public class School {

private int size;
private String name;
private Queue q = new LinkedListQueue();

public School(String n) {
    name = n;
    size = 0;
}

 public void register(Student st) {

    q.enqueue(st);
    size++;

}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void viewStudents() {
    System.out.println(q.toString());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "The School of " + name + ". The number of students is " + size + ".";
    return str;
}
```

So as you can see, I have register method in the School class which register new Student to a specific school.

So my problem is that how can I get data `size` from a School class to use it in the Student class ???

I am only a student don't judge me please ^^)

Comment: Make the size variable static and get it in static way.

Comment: What does this have to do with random?

Comment: I'll admit the connection seems very random to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a student to the school, you should also tell the student what school they're in.

Add a field and a method to `Student`

```
public class Student {
   private String name;
   private int id, size;
   private int dorm;
   private School school;

   public void setSchool( School school ) {
      this.school = school;
   }
```

Then add the code in `School` to tell the student.

```
 public void register(Student st) {  
    q.enqueue(st);
    size++;
    st.setSchool( this );
 }
```

Now as long as `school` is not `null` in Student, a student can find the size of their school.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you need is to add an `int` parameter to your student's `setId()` method:

```
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id * 100 + dorm;
}
```

and then on the `register()` method you would do:

```
public void register(Student st) {
    q.enqueue(st);
    st.setId(size++);
}
```

I hope that helps you, good luck!